# Decouple Unity UIElement (Button) from logic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to decouple logic from Unity UIElement. Ideally, I want to make the UnityEvent LoginButtonClicked pluggable to other scripts. The question is how to respond to different login results

```
public class UILogin: MonoBehaviour
{   
   public TMP_InputField UsernameInputField;
   public TMP_InputField PasswordInputField;   
   public Button ButtonLogin;
   public TMP_Text LoginResult;
    
   /// <summary>
   /// Parameter: Username, password
   /// </summary>
   public UnityEvent<string, string> LoginButtonClicked;

   void Awake() {
       ButtonLogin.onClick.AddListener(() => 
       LoginButtonClicked.Invoke(UsernameInputField.text, PasswordInputField.text));

       /// How to setup a method callback and make the following line happen without setting it somewhere else outside of this class?
       LoginResult.text=?
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like `UIElement` but rather like the `EnityEngine.UI.Button` ...

Comment: And then I don't really understand your use case currently you have a callback for a button ... the `LoginResult` somehow seems to have nothing to do with it. Sounds like you would rather want to have some sort of `LoginController` or however you want to call it and whenever the login button is pressed forward it to the controller and listen to an event on it in order to display the result

Comment: You can add a third Action<string> param to the event, and pass a `ChangeLoginResultText(string text)` method, but Unity won't serialize this, so you'll have to handle this from code, not from the inspector.

Comment: @h4ri Using an Action delegate makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but would it work for you to provide an event that other classes can subscribe to?

```
public class UILogin: MonoBehaviour
{   
   public TMP_InputField UsernameInputField;
   public TMP_InputField PasswordInputField;   
   public Button ButtonLogin;
   // public TMP_Text LoginResult; // Remove here

   public event System.Action onLoginClick;
    
   /// <summary>
   /// Parameter: Username, password
   /// </summary>
   public UnityEvent<string, string> LoginButtonClicked;

   void Awake() {
       ButtonLogin.onClick.AddListener(() => 
       LoginButtonClicked.Invoke(UsernameInputField.text, PasswordInputField.text));

       onLoginClick?.Invoke();
   }
}
```

Then your subscriber could be something like

```
public class LoginResultDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text tmpText;
    public UILogin uiLogin;

    void Awake()
    {
        uiLogin.onLoginClick += OnLoginClick;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        uiLogin.onLoginClick -= OnLoginClick;
    }

    void OnLoginClick()
    {
        tmpText.text = "Login button clicked.";
    }
}
```

But since you said you don't want to set the text from somewhere else, another approach could be to register/unregister a bunch of strings with UILogin. Since you'd need to map the registering object to the string it wants to add, you'd need something like a `Dictionary`, but those don't show up in the Editor by default, so you'd need to do all the handling in code. Something like:

```
public class UILogin: MonoBehaviour
{   
   public TMP_InputField UsernameInputField;
   public TMP_InputField PasswordInputField;   
   public Button ButtonLogin;
   public TMP_Text LoginResult;
   public Dictionary<GameObject, string> loginMessages = new Dictionary<GameObject, string>();
    
   /// <summary>
   /// Parameter: Username, password
   /// </summary>
   public UnityEvent<string, string> LoginButtonClicked;

   void Awake() {
       ButtonLogin.onClick.AddListener(() => 
       LoginButtonClicked.Invoke(UsernameInputField.text, PasswordInputField.text));

       foreach (var kvp in loginMessages)
       {
            LoginResult.text += kvp.Value + "\n";
       }
   }
}
```

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class Messenger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UILogin uiLogin;
    public string message;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        uiLogin.Add(gameObject, $"Hello, I'm {name} and I want to say {message}");
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        uiLogin.Remove(gameObject);
    }
}
```